# Как с помощью функции и цикла изменять один и тот же список?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Происходит зацикливание, не знаю как записать по-другому

```
  def show_magicians(list):
        """Выводит список фокусников"""
        print(magicians)


def make_great(list2):
    while magicians:
        current_magician = "Great "+magicians.pop()
        magicians.append(current_magician)
        print(magicians)
magicians = ['alice','jame','kevin']
make_great(magicians)
```

Comment: Создать список с именами фокусников, передать список функции show_magicians(), которая выводит имя каждого фокусника в списке,
после, написать функцию make_great(), которая изменяет список фокусников, добавляя к имени каждого фокусника приставку "Great".

Comment: Привел код ....

Comment: Помимо прочих *странностей*, цикл `while` будет работать до тех пор, пока `magicians` не опустеет, чего, как вы сами можете видеть, никогда не произойдет.

Comment: поэтому я и написал, что не знаю как записать, лол, с двумя списками легче, а вообще с одним возможно?

Comment: Возможно: в цикле `for` изменяете элементы списка, без удаления/вставки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас зацикливание так как вы идете по списку пока он не кончится и добавляете в него элементы. Получается бесконечный цикл

Вот пример решения вашей задачи

```
def show_magicians(magicians):
    for mag in magicians:
           print(mag)


def make_great(magicians):
    for i in range(len(magicians)):
        magicians[i] = "Great "+magicians[i]
    return magicians



magicians = ['alice','jame','kevin']
magicians=make_great(magicians)

show_magicians(magicians)
```